# How to force a virtual machine to uncache windows domain credentials

Tags: virtualbox, cache, domain, active-directory, credentials

I have

- a Windows 8 host  (latest patches) in an AD domain.
- a windows 7 (latest patches) virtualbox VM also within the the same domain

The issue is that I've been through 2 password change cycles on my domain credentials (via the host) but while logging into the the VM, refuses to accept the changed passwords, and insists on the one that it has cached.

I've tried the solutions suggested on MSDN : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itpronetworking/thread/ced8eab6-87e2-4d20-9d18-7aaf5e9713a3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it.

I missed one of the solutions in the above technical article:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itpronetworking/thread/ced8eab6-87e2-4d20-9d18-7aaf5e9713a3

due to a setting on my VM.

- Set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon set CachedLogonsCount` to 0
- reboot
- Set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon set CachedLogonsCount` to original value (10 in my case)

After I did this I got an issue with Logon Servers not being available and I realised that the real issue was the the VM networking was switched to NAT - so my VM was not actually seeing the domain.

Switching this back to bridged I was able to to see the domain and I was able to use the new credentials.

Hope this helps someone.